# Mod_rewrite failing to silently redirect

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

2 days of struggling and about a pound less of hair, I figure it's about time I ask for some help.  I've recently migrated my project to a main sub-directory so that the structure is as follows:

```
-application/
   -index.php
   -signup/
      -index.php
      -signup_set.php
-css/
-js/
```

I've been trying to get mod_rewrite to do my work for me to exclude "application/" from all the urls.  Here is where I got in my root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 

#first round through, prepend 'application/' to request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^application

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/$1 [L]

#second round through, if the new url is not directory or file, append .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

I may have a terrible understanding of regex/mod_rewrite, but this actually seems to partly work.  Partly.  The weird part about this is that when I route to a "pretty url" (e.g. www/signup) the url in the top bar is physically rewritten to include the "application/" (e.g. www/application/signup).  So somehow this "silent" rewriting process is getting pretty loud...Any suggestions?  I realize I could change my root directory but that would require rewriting of code referencing css/js files.  I'm more curious than anything, just trying my hand at some htaccess.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks StackOverflow, you rock.

P.S. I'm running Apache on Windows 7 and using a virtual host (in case any of that is relevant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules below work for me running Apache on Windows 7 using a virtual host. All I changed was the second `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Append trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]

# First round through, prepend 'application/' to request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/$1 [L]

# Second round through, if the new url is not directory or file, append .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Well, it must be something else on my system then because it still refuses to work properly.  All well!  "A" for effort (+ a check and an upvote).

Comment: Sorry. I just realized that I had not fully mimicked your directory structure when I was testing this out earlier. I just modified my answer to append a trailing slash at the start, and to remove it before adding the ".php" extension. This is working for me on my local machine with a directory structure matching the one outlined in your OP. I'm not 100% happywith it; it feels a little wonky to me, but it seems to get the job done. Hope it works for you as well!

Comment: Bravo! You have cracked the code.  It is simple and easy-to-follow.  I figured it had something to do with a trailing slash being left out or added along the way, but debugging for that is extremely difficult. Thanks, @rexmac!